# How do message queue response codes work?

Tags: response, message-queue

Currently my company has a message queue that takes in third party requests, and consumes them on one of our applications. However, there is no way for the third party to know if the request was successful. All of the requests made to our messaging queue return responses `{code: 200, message: "successfully placed on queue"}`.

We're currently using a script to look through the logs every day and create a report with all the failures. I don't have a lot of knowledge about message queues but this just seems like what we're doing is really bad practice.

What is the best practice for handling this situation?

Comment: The issue with this is that usually the errors happen asynchronously to the request. Usually you either give a hook to run of failure, or open a different queue for errors for the client to consume and respond to. Another option is to respond with a request id and let the client query the status.

Comment: Thanks for your response. "give a hook to run of failure" By this do you mean upon failure, send some sort of failure response/message to the client?

"open a different queue for errors" And I'm assuming by this you also mean creating some failure queue and sending the failures back to the client? If so, the only weird thing is that the client would have to setup an endpoint to retrieve the returned failures.

Comment: Yes thats what i mean. Again, this is because i can theoretically post a message to the queue now and it can be processed minutes from now. Noone wants to keep an http connection alive that long